# ROS2 Humble / Gazebo Fortress - no sensor data published by force_torque sensor

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ignition

I am using ROS Humble in combination with Gazebo Fortress (v6.16.0).

Using URDF / XACRO I am inserting a `force_torque` sensor into a rotary joint of my model.

```
<xacro:macro name="tibia_joint" params="prefix *origin">

    <joint name="${prefix}/tibia" type="continuous">
    <parent link="${prefix}_femur_link"/>
        <child link="${prefix}_tibia_link"/>
    <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="100" velocity="${pi}" lower="-${pi/4}" upper="${pi/4}" />
        <dynamics damping="1.0"/> <!-- 1.0 N*m*s/rad -->
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="${prefix}/tibia">
    <sensor name="${prefix}/tibia/force_torque" type="force_torque">
            <update_rate>100</update_rate>
            <topicName>/model/L4XZ/joint/leg/${prefix}/tibia/angle/force_torque</topicName>
        <jointName>${prefix}/tibia</jointName>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
</xacro:macro>
```

When bringing up the gazebo and instantiating the model I can see the instantiation of the force_torque sensor worked:

[image]

However, when I run `ign topic --list` I see no topic with force_torque sensor values being published. (Note: other topics just as joint positions are published just fine and show up in `ign topic --list`).

What do I need to do to obtain the data measured by the force_torque sensor plugin?

Comment: The answer is actually over in this comment: https://github.com/gazebosim/docs/issues/331#issuecomment-1885104467 . You need to load the plugin in <world> tag and only then can you instantiate it within your model.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and not as a comment.